# Robotium Test Case For Android (System Dialog can not find OK and Cancel Buttons)

Tags: android, dialog, system

i have a problem about robotium. I can click my custom dialog view's ok and cancel buttons. But in system dialog, solo can not find ok, cancel buttons, texts or any view in dialog. How can i solve this problem?

Created Dialog code is below:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", bean.packageName, null);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, uri);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: By "system" do you mean a non-custom Dialog still created in your own Activity context?

Comment: Yes, created by system via context. I editted the entry contains dialog code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robotium can only access views that belong to your application, for example it can't interact with the Notification Bar's views. Since you're not creating a dialog, you're starting an intent that causes the system to create a dialog, you can't access those views.

Comment: Pro tip: on StackOverflow, if someone answers your question and you're satisfied with the answer, you click the little checkmark to the left of the answer to accept it. You can only accept one answer per question. If you find other answers helpful, you can upvote as many as you like. (Click the up arrow to the left of the question to upvote it.) People are more likely to answer your questions if you respond that way.